# Admob smart banner ads not updating on device rotation

Tags: ios, admob, screen-orientation

I am trying to implement Admob's smart banner ads. I am unable to find a way to deal with updating the ad when the device is rotated. According to AdMob's docs, setting the `adSize` property will cause the ad to reload. This works for the standard banner ads, but it doesn't seem to work with the smart banner ads.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.gadBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    self.gadBannerView.adUnitID = @"myBannerID";
    self.gadBannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.gadBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.gadBannerView];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.view.bounds.size.width < self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        // portrait orientation
        self.gadBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait;
        NSLog(@"portrait banner size: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.gadBannerView.frame));
    } else {
        // landscape orientation
        self.gadBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
        NSLog(@"landscape banner size: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.gadBannerView.frame));
    }
}
```

The ads stay at the size that they were when the object is initialized. I also tried setting the `GADBannerView` object to `nil` and then initializing it again, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with version 7.2.2 of AdMob iOS SDK.

v7.3.1 includes a fix for your problem (see [AdMob iOS release notes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes)):

> Fixed a regression introduced in 7.2.0 where smart banners displayed
>   incorrectly in landscape on iOS 8.